# How to compare two LinkedList present under a Map datastructure?

Tags: java

I have got a Map as shown below

```
Map<String,LinkedList<Integer>> vendoritemsmap = new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedList<Integer>>();

LinkedList<Integer> listforkeyone = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        listforkeyone.add(1);
        listforkeyone.add(2);



LinkedList<Integer> listforkeytwo = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        listforkeytwo.add(1);


vendoritemsmap.put("11111", listforkeyone);
vendoritemsmap.put("11112", listforkeytwo);


LinkedList<Integer> llforforsearch = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        llforforsearch.add(1);
        llforforsearch.add(2);
```

I was search for in which key the values of llforforsearch matahces

```
for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : vendoritemsmap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        LinkedList<Integer> list = entry.getValue();
        if(list.contains(llforforsearch))
        {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
```

But its not working , could anybody tell me how can i compare the equality of two LinkedLists ???

Comment: Could you repharse this sentence: I was search for in which key the values of llforforsearch matahces

Answer (score 1):

[`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) checks if the given element can be found in the list. Try [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) (or [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)) instead.